# GeoFire query completion - Swift

Tags: swift, location, geofire, koloda

In my app, I use `GeoFire` to query users around user location.
It is a Tinder-like app, with cards, etc... I use `KolodaView` for cards.

### Query function :

```
func queryUsers(searchRadius: Int, center: CLLocation) {

    print("Query started")

    let geofireRef = Database.database().reference().child("usersLocations")
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)

    let circleQuery = geoFire?.query(at: center, withRadius: Double(searchRadius))

    _ = circleQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (result, location) in

        print("User \(result!) found")
        print("Adding user \(result!)")

        addUser(userID: result!, completionHandler: { (success) in

            print("User added")

        })

    })

}
```

### Add user function :

```
func addUser(userID: String, completionHandler:@escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

    let foundUsers = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "foundUsers")

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if (foundUsers?.count)! < 20 {

            // USERS

            let users = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["users"] as! NSDictionary

            // USER

            let user = users[userID] as! NSDictionary

            getFirstUserPicture(userID: userID, completionHandler: { (data) in

                if let data = data {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        user.setValue(data, forKey: "picture")

                        // APPEND FOUND USERS ARRAY

                        var foundUsers = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "foundUsers")

                        foundUsers?.append(user)

                        // STORE FOUND USERS ARRAY

                        UserDefaults.standard.set(foundUsers, forKey: "foundUsers")
                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                        // UPDATE CARD VIEW

                        if foundUsers?.count == 1 {

                            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .loadCardView, object: nil)

                        } else {

                            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .loadCardsInArray, object: nil)

                        }

                        // COMPLETION

                        completionHandler(true)

                    }

                }

            })

        }

    }) { (error) in

        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }

}
```

When I launch the app, the `queryUsers` function is called, the query 
starts

### Output

```
User 1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX found
Adding user 1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
User 2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX found
Adding user 2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
User added
User added
```

1. User is found
2. Adding user (call `addUser` function)

The problem is that it didn't wait the `addUser` completion to call `addUser` for the second user found. The result is that in my `KolodaView`, there is the second user found two times
because I think the call of `addUser` for the second user found uses first user found parameters.

Is it possible to wait for the first `addUser` completion and start again the query ? Or just "pause" the query after the first user was found, and start it again after the completion of the first `addUser` call ?

Thanks for your help

### Update 1

I tried the @Rlee128 solution but nothing changed, I have the same output :( :

```
// MARK: UPDATE USER LOCATION - FUNCTION

func updateUserLocation() {

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("usersLocations")
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: databaseRef)

    let userID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userID")!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    geoFire?.setLocation(locationManager.location, forKey: userID, withCompletionBlock: { (error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error as Any)

        } else {

            // Location updated

        }

    })

}


// MARK: LOCATION MANAGER DELEGATE - FUNCTION

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    manager.delegate = nil

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In then location manger didUpdateLocations set manager.delegate to = nil after you call manager.stopUpdatingLocation(). Let me know if you want me to show you how it looks in my code.

```
func findLocation() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    manager.delegate = nil
    let loc = CLLocation(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    getLocation(location: loc)

}
```